# Forge Viewer - Markups - can we get xy coordinates of the current selection?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

I am using markup extension to draw on my viewer, after drawing, on selection of markup event, can I get its center coordinates of current selection or any coordinates inside of it?
if not, at least can I get dbId behind current selection?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried putting     var pos = markup.markups[0].getClientPosition(). Is this a proper solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yelp~ it's the case, and see also:

```
// Get the markup's position in browser pixel space. the (0,0) is top left
Markup#getClientPosition()
```

```
// Get the markup's bounding rect in browser pixel space.

Markup#getClientSize()
```

```
// get the markup's bounding rect in browser pixel space, including the stroke width

Markup#getBoundingRect()
```

BTW, to obtain dbId within the markup boundary, you can do this:

1. Get markup's BoundingRect  in browser's pixel space
2. Convert coordinates of the rect's vertices into viewer's 3d space via
   [Viewer3D#clientToWorld](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#clienttoworld-clientx-clienty-ignoretransparent)
3. Do bounding box collision to find out intersected mesh for the dbId, see here for the example:
   https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-window-selection-forge-viewer-simpler-extension